# Error accessing BigQuery using DirectRunner

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to access a BigQuery table from my pipeline, everything works ok when using DataflowRunner but I get the following error when using DirectRunner.

```
WARNING:root:Dataset does not exist so we will create it
WARNING:root:Task failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/executor.py", line 300, in __call__
    result = evaluator.finish_bundle()
  File "local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/transform_evaluator.py", line 209, in finish_bundle
    bundles = _read_values_to_bundles(reader)
  File "local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/transform_evaluator.py", line 196, in _read_values_to_bundles
    read_result = [GlobalWindows.windowed_value(e) for e in reader]
  File "local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py", line 606, in __iter__
    yield self.client.convert_row_to_dict(row, schema)
  File "local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py", line 1073, in convert_row_to_dict
    for x in value]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

This is code snippet that initializes the runner:

```
options = {
    'project':
        args.project_id,
}
pipeline_options = beam.pipeline.PipelineOptions(flags=[], **options)
```

UPDATE:

Here is a snippet of the relevant part where the pipeline is constructed.

```
reader = (
    pipeline
    | 'ReadFromBigQuery %s' % query_path >> beam.io.Read(
        beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query, use_standard_sql=True)))
readers.append(reader)
readers | 'FlattenPaths %s' % ':'.join(path_names) >> beam.Flatten()
```

Comment: can you share your pipeline code?

Comment: Do you set flatten_results to 'False' when creating the BQ source transform ? If so this could be due to fix https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/2289 which is not released yet.

Comment: I updated the post with the relevant portion of the pipeline. @chamikaram the PR you linked seems related, I'll wait for the next release.